# Laravel 5.6 - Get route name in javsascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.6 project with a JS file in the public directory.

I am looking for a way to get the route name within the javascript file. I need to set a variable in the javascript depending on the route.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just place a script tag on the view you want to access it from:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var token='{{csrf_token()}}' ;
    var AuthCheck='{{Auth::check()}}';
    var currentRoute='{{Route::current()}}'
</script>
```

Comment: This will only be available while put on current view, if we refactor to other file such as `file.js`, it'll not able to get php element. By the way, I would add attribute to a html element. ex: `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="startBtn" data-url="{{ route('route') }}" onclick="alert($(this).attr('data-url')"></button>`